# My Subtraction Code In Javascript Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, subtraction

I am trying to work on subtracting 2 values in Javascript. I had the addition working and then I just copied the code for subtraction (I just changed the operator). But I am wondering why the subtraction is not working. Can you please tell me what did I miss?

Here's the code:

```
<script language="javascript">
            function subNumbers()
            {
                    var gross = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Gross").value);
                    var tax   = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Tax").value);
                    var other = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Other").value);
                    var ded   = document.getElementById("TotalDed");
                    ded.value = tax + other;
                    var net   = document.getElementById("Net");
                    net.value = gross - ded;
            }
    </script>
```

And then in the html part:

```
<input onchange="subNumbers()" type="text" id="Gross" name="Gross" value="" />
<input onchange="subNumbers()" type="text" id="Tax" name="Tax" value="" />
<input onchange="subNumbers()" type="text" id="Other" name="Other" value="" />
<input onchange="subNumbers()" type="text" id="TotalDed" name="TotalDed" value="" />
<input type="text" name="Net" value="" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="Net" value="" />
```

becomes

```
<input type="text" name="Net" id="Net" value="" />
```

and

```
net.value = gross - ded;
```

becomes

```
net.value = gross - ded.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that:

`<input type="text" name="Net" value="" />`

Does not have an `id` attribute specified. Without `id`, `document.getElementById('net');` fails.

Change it to:

`<input type="text" id="net" value="" />`

And `ded` is an object, you need to use `.value` for both `ded` and `net` variables.